# C client can only connect to localhost.

Tags: c, sockets, client, telnet

My C client can connect to my server on local, but when I try connecting from a remote machine it does not connect, it reaches as "error connect failed".

I am able to telnet into the server from remote machines.

```
     char* user_IP;
            printf("Please enter an IP Address\n");
731
732            scanf(" %s", user_IP);
733            /*while (isdigit(IP) && IP>0)        // has some isues           
734            {                                                                
735                printf("Please enter an IP Address\n");                      
736                                                                             
737                scanf(" %s", &IP);                                           
738                }*/
739            play_num=2;
740            IP=atoi(user_IP);
741
742
743            if((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
744            {
745                printf("\n Error : Could not create socket \n");
746                return 1;
747            }
748
749            memset(&serv_addr,0,sizeof(serv_addr));
750            serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
751            serv_addr.sin_port = htons(5001);
752
753            if( connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_a\
   ddr)) < 0)
754            {
755                printf("\n Error : Connect Failed \n");
756                return 1;
757            }
```

Comment: `user_IP` doesn't point to memory before you use `scanf`. This will clearly crash.

Comment: You don't appear to be using the `IP` variable anywhere, and you've zeroed `serv_addr`, so `serv_addr.sin_addr` is zero. Also, `atoi` is not the correct way to parse an IP address string; it parses integers; see `inet_aton` instead.

Comment: that was it dont know how i missed something that simple THANKS!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems.

1. You have not used IP address anywhere in the connection.
2. You don't store anything when you use `scanf()`. Use something like:

   ```
   Char user_IP[16];

   Scanf("%s", user_IP);
   ```